# how to push data down a row in sql results

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I would like help with sql query code to push the consequent data in a specific column down by a row. 
For example in a random table like the following,

```
x column                y column
6                       6
9                       4
89                      30
34                      15
```

the results should be "pushed" down a row, meaning

```
x column                y column
6                       null or 0 (preferably) 
9                       6
89                      4
34                      30
```

Comment: You might want to format this to make better sense.

Comment: This is just curiosity on my part: why would you want to do this?

Comment: what does it have to do with sql ?

Comment: You don't seem to have any ordering defined? Rows don't have inherent order, so "down" doesn't mean anything without specifying your order-by.

Comment: Do you have an auto-incrementing primary key?

Comment: Key question is why... why do you want to do this?

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are your using (mySQL, SQL Server, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables have no inherent concept of ordering.  Hence, the concept of "next row" does not make sense.

Your example has no column that specifies the order for the rows.  There is no definition of next.  So, what you want to do cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a simple way to do this with the way you are showing the table being formatted.  If your perhaps added two consecutively numbered integer fields that provide row number and row number + 1 values, you could join the table to itself and get that information.

Comment: my apologies. I was not aware that the table was not properly formatted. do you mean adding 1 column "test1" with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc as its rows and another column "test2" with 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 then joining it to the original column? and then moving the values in the original column (the example i provided in the question would be 6, 4, 30 and 15) such that any value from the subset(6, 4, 30, 15) which will be paired with a value in test2 by matching row numbers, would be moved to the corresponding value in test1.

Comment: @user1569897 That is the jist of it, though there wouldn't be moving of values it would be like `SELECT a.columnx, b.columny FROM tablename as a JOIN tablename as b on a.test1 = b.test2`

Answer (score 0):

After taking a backup of you table:
Make a PHP function that will:
 - Load all values of Y into an array
 - Set Y = 0 (MYSQL UPDATE)
 - load the values back from PHP array to MYSQL